# how Setup NS1/NS2 For My VPS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, configuration, ns-record

I'm running a site on a dedicated server:
`(vps = virtual private network, with windows server 2008, IIS & DNS has been installed without any configs, have one dedicated IP address)`

I am  trying to setup DNS correctly for a specific domain (**[www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)**).
How do I properly setup the `ns1` and `ns2` nameservers and web zones for that domain, so its publicly live and viewable?

I'm running Windows Server 2008 r2 as the administrator user.
I am a system web developer and am so sorry for lack of knowledge about this situation, but I want to learn it step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably leave the DNS (primary and secondary) pointing at the VPS provider's nameservers and just update your DNS records (www = w.x.y.z) with whoever hosts your domain name.

Since you only have 1 IP address assigned I don't think you intend to host your own DNS nameservers. Better just remove the DNS role from the server.